# Changing column based on multiple conditions and previous rows values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe. I need to replace NaNs in column **rank** to a value based on multiple conditions. If column **min** is higher than 3 previous rows of **max** column then **rank** equals to **min**. Otherwise, I need to copy the previous value of **rank**

```
      max     min    rank
0  128.20  117.87  117.87
1  132.72  122.29  122.29
2  138.07  124.89  124.89
3  137.02  128.46     NaN
4  130.91  129.86     NaN
5  200.15  190.54     NaN
6  199.18  191.79     NaN
7  210.44  201.94     NaN
```

The desired result is

```
      max     min    rank
0  128.20  117.87  117.87
1  132.72  122.29  122.29
2  138.07  124.89  124.89
3  137.02  128.46  124.89
4  130.91  129.86  124.89
5  200.15  190.54  190.54
6  199.18  191.79  190.54
7  210.44  201.94  201.94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df['rank'].mask(pd.concat([df['min'].shift(i) for i in range(3)], 1).apply(
    lambda x: x < df['min']).all(1), df['min']).ffill()
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
      max     min    rank
0  128.20  117.87  117.87
1  132.72  122.29  122.29
2  138.07  124.89  124.89
3  137.02  128.46  124.89
4  130.91  129.86  124.89
5  200.15  190.54  190.54
6  199.18  191.79  190.54
7  210.44  201.94  201.94
```

Comment: Thanks, simly perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df["rank"].update(df[df["min"]>df["max"].rolling(3).max().shift(1)]["min"])
df["rank"].ffill(inplace=True)
>>> df
      max     min    rank
0  128.20  117.87  117.87
1  132.72  122.29  122.29
2  138.07  124.89  124.89
3  137.02  128.46  124.89
4  130.91  129.86  124.89
5  200.15  190.54  190.54
6  199.18  191.79  190.54
7  210.44  201.94  201.94
```

The `rolling` and `shift` functions are being used to check if the current `min` is greater than the `max` of the three previous `max`.

The `ffill` carries forward the previous value.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I chose another answer as correct just because it is only one line of code, but yours also works without any problems